What are final segments of a free monoid?
In th paper Free monoids and generalized metric spaces, the authors refer to the "set of final segments of $A^*$" where $A^*$ is the free monoid on some alphabet. Since they do not define the notion of final segment, I assume that it is common in the field. Unfortunately, I can not tell what it means from context nor have I been able to find the definition anywhere else. So, what is a final segment?

The full phrase they use is "final segment of $A^{\ast}$ equipped with the Higman ordering." So this is about the order, and googling with that in mind produces a paper with the definition here: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~matthias/pdf/finitegeninvarideals.pdf
